# query last image in shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I’m trying to add a link to a size guide image by having it pull the last image from a collection.

but right now it’s pulling all the images, not the last. how do i just pull the last?

```
 <!-- SIZE GUIDE -->
         <div id=“size_guide”>
 {% for image in product.images %}
 <a href=“{{ image.src | product_img_url: ‘master’ }}” class=“fancybox-media {% cycle ‘,last’ %}”>
 SIZE GUIDE</a> {% endfor %}
          </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`last` array filter](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#last). E.g:

```
<a href="{{ product.images.last | product_img_url: 'master' }}">SIZE GUIDE</a>
```

Comment: ok that partially worked. but i'm getting a 404 now. any ideas?

Comment: figured out it's getting a 404 because it's outputting a double URL. it's appending the name of the webpage with the URL of the image. how do i fix that?

Comment: @rs202 Just tested it and it's working fine for me. I simplified the code in my answer a bit, but I cant reproduce the error you're getting. Can you post your code, and a link to the page if possible?